# Merge multiple tabs, download as CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dozen sheets in a google folder. With the script below I can get the first tab of each file to be copied in a new spreadsheet. 
But now I want all the data to be copied in just one tab, and have it downloaded as csv file to a a shared drive (not google apps). The format of the data is always the same, just sometimes the number of rows differs per sheet.

In addition, I would like to select the tab based on name instead of number - to avoid errors in the future. Any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

```
function mergeSheets() {

/* Retrieve the desired folder */
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('name of folder').next();

/* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-    apps.spreadsheet");

/* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

/* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

/* Open the spreadsheet */
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

/* Get all its sheets */
//    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

  /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
  spreadSheet.getSheets()[0].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
//    }
}      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is another possible solution to compile all the spreadsheets from a folder into a single spreadsheet sheet using a faster method ([concatenate arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)).

The only restriction is that all the sheets must have the same number of columns (row number is not important)

From this single sheet it will be easy to export its contnet to CSV and save it as a drive file.
I used your code as a starting point and commented the part that iterate all the sheets in each spreadsheet just as you did but you can of course uncomment the for loop).
I added a few comments to explain the procedure.

```
function mergeSheets() {
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  //var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('name of folder').next();
  // or better 
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3qSFd3iikE3RDhxekVYNk5zUkk');

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
  var newSheetTab = newSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var values = [] ;// new array to get all sheets contents
  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  var header = [];
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    Logger.log(sheet.getName()); // log the sheet name to check
    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    //    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

    //for(var sheet in spreadSheet.getSheets()){
      var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];// comment this line if you keep the for loop
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      var data = range.getValues();
      if(header.length==0){ 
        header = data.shift(); // get the header only once and remove header from data in the same time
      }else{
        var dummy = data.shift(); // remove header from data but don't keep it
      }
      values = values.concat(data); // add data to final array in each while loop 
   // }
  }
  values.unshift(header); // add the header at the array start
  Logger.log(values);//see result
  newSheetTab.getRange(1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);// batch write to the sheet
}

// then export this single sheet as CSV see code from Google tuto
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section-3-saving-a-selected-range-to-a-csv-file
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works like charm! Just a little question, how do I get a column with dates in date-format in the merged sheet?

Comment: You can set the format in a range with [setNumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) , for example define your range with getRange('A2:A') for col 'A' and then set the format of that range to "mm/dd/yyyy" to show dates as mm/dd/yyyy in column A.

Comment: Regarding the last comment in the code: the DocsList service is no longer functional: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeSheets() {

/* Retrieve the desired folder */
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('name of folder').next();

/* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-    apps.spreadsheet");

/* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
var newSheetTab = newSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();

/* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

/* Open the spreadsheet */
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

/* Get all its sheets */
//    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

  /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
  var range = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('sheet name').getDataRange();

    // start after header row
    // may have to adjust these upon desired effect
    for (var i = 1; i < range.getNumRows(); i++)
    {
      newSheetTab.appendRow(range[i]);
    }

//    }
}

// then save as csv
}
```

Refer to [this blog](https://www.drzon.net/export-all-google-sheets-to-csv/) on how to save as csv.

Comment: your script could be **a lot faster** if instead of appending rows you get the whole dataRange values as arrays that you would concatenate in one big resulting array and then write this array at once to the destination sheet.

Comment: Yes it could, this was just a quick code write on the go for a solution he needed

Comment: I understand for sure but nevertheless it is a typical case where the suggested script might be disappointing (if not unuseable if he has a lot of data) for a user that ignores GAS best practices. That's why I mentioned it here.

Comment: I did a quick search of appending a range, didn't find any quick methods. I know of a way to get the desired effect, but again didn't have the time to put in the extra effort. Feel free to add a script with said practice as an answer, otherwise if I get time later, I'll update my answer. 