# Merge Multiple CSV Files in single file on gdrive

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to merge multiple csv files into single csv file from Google drive Folder, but I'm unable to do it as it works well with google sheets but not with csv files.

I used the code that is already available on stackoverflow.com but it didn't work well with my requirements.

```
function mergeSheets() {

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test 1").next();

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("MimeType.csv");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}
```

It does create a new sheet but without any csv data.

Answer (score 2):

The main problems with your solution were:

1. You create the new merged sheet even if you don't find any CSV to merge.
2. You were trying to get CSV files with the wrong mimetype string. (invalid `"MimeType.csv"` vs correct `"text/csv"`. Alternatively, just `MimeType.csv` without quotes would work too.)
3. You assumed that opening a csv with Spreadsheets app was possible, when it isn't.

To fix those issues I have:

1. Added a check before creating the merge file.
2. Fixed the mimetype string to the correct one.
3. Switched the `SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());` with `Utilities.parseCsv(sheet.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");` so we can [open a csv file](https://ctrlq.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet) propperly.
4. Added logic to add the rows one by one.

Here is some code that works in putting multiple csv files into a single spreadsheet, each file on its own sheet.

```
function mergeSheets() {
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test 1").next();  
  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("text/csv");
  if (spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */
    var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
    /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
    while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
      var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
      /* Load the csv data */
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(sheet.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      var newSheet = newSpreadSheet.insertSheet("import_"+sheet.getName());
      for (var i=0;i<csvData.length;i++) {
        newSheet.appendRow(csvData[i]);
      }
    } 
  }   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: found a way to use **MimeType.CSV** and that worked for my solution. Perhaps take a peek at that to see if there are any anomalies in doing so?

Comment: @AghaMusaKhan no problem! Remember to approve the answer that was more helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to it:

- involves using **MimeType.CSV** (the OP just had to avoid using quotes )
- involves adding rows from one csv to the new Spreadsheet - altogether, instead of iterating through rows one after the other

Try this -

```
function mergeSheets() {

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test 1").next();

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();


    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var newSheet = newSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
    newSheet.getRange(newSpreadSheet.getLastRow() + 1, newSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()+1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);



  }      
}
```

I'm assuming you must've gotten the idea of the original code from here - [Merge multiple tabs, download as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647769/merge-multiple-tabs-download-as-csv)

I found my inspiration from this article [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet).

Comment: It works the best according to my requirement, as it appends the csv files in single sheet, now i just have to remove first row from every csv sheet as the title in every csv sheet is same and all i need is the user data.  Thanks for the help and yes i get the idea of it from your given link.

Comment: @AghaMusaKhan - glad that this helped :) Kindly consider accepting the answer too - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @AghaMusaKhan If you would like to auto remove the first row you can always take the `code` csvData = csvDataslice(0); // make copy
csvDatasplice(0, 1);`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeCSVFiles(folderId,filename) {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.csv);
  var s='';
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    s+=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  }
  var currentFiles=DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFilesByName(filename);
  while(currentFiles.hasNext()) {
    currentFiles.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile(filename,s,”text/csv”);//The merged file is in your root folder. 
}
```

Comment: I had to change the "MimeType.csv" to "text/csv" and then it workes the best. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: Thanks for catching that